# Reading from Kafka topic using Spark Structured Streaming: Can multi-line JSON published to Kafka topic be parsed by Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Can it be possible to parse/read the multi-line JSON published to Kafka topic by spark using Structured streaming?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using spark version greater than 2.2, following would work.

```
 spark.read
  .option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
  .json("/path/to/user.json")
```

Comment: This is for batch processing. For streaming Will it work using spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", broker)
  .option("subscribe", topic).option("multiLine", true)  ?